# Is it possible to ack nagios alerts from the terminal?

Tags: scripting, nagios

I have nagios alerts set up to come through jabber with an http link to ack.

Is is possible there is a script I can run from a terminal on a remote workstation that takes the hostname as a parameter and acks the alert?

./ack hostname

The benefit, while seemingly mundane, is threefold. First, take http load off nagios. Secondly, nagios http pages can take up to 10-20 seconds to load, so I want to save time there. Thirdly, avoiding slower use of mouse + web interface + firefox/other annoyingly slow browser.

Ideally, I would like a script bound to a keyboard shortcut that simply acks the most recent alert. Finally, I want to take the inputs from a joystick, buttons and whatnot, and connect one to a big red button bound to the script so I can just ack the most recent nagios alert by hitting the button lol. (It would be rad too if the button had a screen on the enclosure that showed the text of the alert getting acked lol)

Make fun of me all you want, but this is actually something that would be useful to me. If I can save five seconds per alert, and I get 200 alerts per day I need to ack, that's saving me 15 minutes a day. And isn't the whole point of the sysadmin to automate what can be automated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to ack nagios by parsing `/var/lib/nagios3/retention.dat` file.

See :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
# vim:ts=4:sw=4

import sys

file = "/var/lib/nagios3/retention.dat"

try:
    sys.argv[1]
except:
    print("Usage:\n"+sys.argv[0]+" <HOST>\n")
    sys.exit(1)

f = open(file, "r")
line = f.readline()

c=0
name = {}
state = {}
host = {}

while line:
    if "service_description=" in line:
        name[c] = line.split("=", 2)[1]
    elif "current_state=" in line:
        state[c] = line.split("=", 2)[1]
    elif "host_name=" in line:
        host[c] = line.split("=", 2)[1]
    elif "}" in line:
        c+=1

    line = f.readline()

for i in name:
    num = int(state[i])

    if num > 0 and sys.argv[1] == host[i].strip():
        print(name[i].strip("\n"))
```

You simply have to put the host as parameter, and the script will displays the broken services.

Comment: Not at all! I'm just slow haha. I also realized I should have posted this on server fault. I'm assuming you run the script from the nagios server? I was hoping for something that can be run from a remote workstation but I should have clarified that.

Comment: Yes, from the nagios server. You can do the same on the remote host with ssh : `ssh nagios-server /path/to/executable/script.py`